# redirect to https url with get parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have .htaccess file and code gives only https on pages of woocommerce shop and works perfectly. So how can I add rule that let https on page with GET parameter 'yandex_money=check' for example https://example.com/?yandex_money=check

```
RewriteEngine On
    # Force HTTPS for /(cart|checkout|my-account|product-category|shop|product)
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/(cart|checkout|my-account|product-category|shop|product) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(cart|checkout|my-account|product-category|shop|product) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

    # Force HTTP for anything which isn't /(cart|checkout|my-account|product-category|shop|product)
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\s/(cart|checkout|my-account|product-category|shop|product) [NC]
    RewriteRule !^(cart|checkout|my-account|product-category|shop|product) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is

- adding RewriteCond about %{REQUEST_URI} with [OR]
- replace RewriteRule [L] with RewriteRule [N] and RewriteRule [L].
- [N] key allows to check Next RewriteRule
- [L] last is RewriteRule.

fixed .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
# RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS for /(cart|checkout|my-account|product-category|shop|product|wp-admin|wp-login) GET[yandex_money]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/(cart|checkout|my-account|product-category|shop|product|wp-admin|wp-login) [OR,NC]
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^yandex_money=check [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

RewriteRule ^(cart|checkout|my-account|product-category|shop|product|wp-admin|wp-login) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}[NC,R=301,N]
RewriteRule ^(yandex_money) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}[NC,R=301,L]

# Force HTTP for anything which isn't /(cart|checkout|my-account|product-category|shop|product|wp-admin|wp-login)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\s/(cart|checkout|my-account|product-category|shop|product|wp-admin|wp-login) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^yandex_money=check [NC]
RewriteRule !^(cart|checkout|my-account|product-category|shop|product|wp-admin|wp-login) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}
```